# Trying to get the background image to show

Tags: navbar

Hey I'm working on building a 3D website for my portfolio piece and I'm running into a issue. I'm trying to get my navbar to show when I'm minimizing my screen but that isn't working.here is my code for that:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MOGg.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffwny.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcx8l.png)

I've tred commiting out my code and starting over. I've looked up tutorials but nothing is working for me.